# MOSQL: Data type: JSON ARRAY return SQL literal (Sequel::Error

Tags: ruby, json, mongodb

I've been doing testing with this tool to migrate data from mongo db and this one of the issue that I have yet to find out a solution... been wondering a while looking for a solution... but there's no clear solution until now. Please find the stack trace below..

mosql version unknown (but when I try to uninstall the mosql, it mentions the version of mosql-0.4.3
ruby version: ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [x64-mingw32]

I made a changes to cli.rb under this folder C:\Ruby22-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.2.0\gems\mosql-0.4.3\lib\mosql to delete "USR2" at line 27 from the list to fix issue of running mosql.

```
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sequel-4.34.0/lib/sequel/dataset/sql.rb:1252:in `literal_other_append': can't express BSON::ObjectId('5656805534616f4c317b7bff') as a SQL literal (Sequel::Error)
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sequel-4.34.0/lib/sequel/dataset/sql.rb:108:in `literal_append'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sequel-4.34.0/lib/sequel/dataset/sql.rb:486:in `complex_expression_sql_append'

from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sequel-4.34.0/lib/sequel/adapters/shared/postgres.rb:1272:in `complex_expression_sql_append'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sequel-4.34.0/lib/sequel/sql.rb:109:in `to_s_append'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sequel-4.34.0/lib/sequel/dataset/sql.rb:1214:in `literal_expression_append'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sequel-4.34.0/lib/sequel/dataset/sql.rb:86:in `literal_append'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sequel-4.34.0/lib/sequel/dataset/sql.rb:494:in `block in complex_expression_sql_append'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sequel-4.34.0/lib/sequel/dataset/sql.rb:492:in `each'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sequel-4.34.0/lib/sequel/dataset/sql.rb:492:in `complex_expression_sql_append'

from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sequel-4.34.0/lib/sequel/adapters/shared/postgres.rb:1272:in `complex_expression_sql_append'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sequel-4.34.0/lib/sequel/sql.rb:109:in `to_s_append'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sequel-4.34.0/lib/sequel/dataset/sql.rb:1214:in `literal_expression_append'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sequel-4.34.0/lib/sequel/dataset/sql.rb:1229:in `literal_hash_append'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sequel-4.34.0/lib/sequel/dataset/sql.rb:84:in `literal_append'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sequel-4.34.0/lib/sequel/extensions/pg_array.rb:504:in `block in _literal_append'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sequel-4.34.0/lib/sequel/extensions/pg_array.rb:499:in `each'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sequel-4.34.0/lib/sequel/extensions/pg_array.rb:499:in `_literal_append'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sequel-4.34.0/lib/sequel/extensions/pg_array.rb:483:in `sql_literal_append'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sequel-4.34.0/lib/sequel/dataset/sql.rb:1248:in `literal_other_append'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sequel-4.34.0/lib/sequel/dataset/sql.rb:108:in `literal_append'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sequel-4.34.0/lib/sequel/dataset/sql.rb:1576:in `block in update_sql_values_hash'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sequel-4.34.0/lib/sequel/dataset/sql.rb:1568:in `each'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sequel-4.34.0/lib/sequel/dataset/sql.rb:1568:in `update_sql_values_hash'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sequel-4.34.0/lib/sequel/dataset/sql.rb:1559:in `update_set_sql'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sequel-4.34.0/lib/sequel/dataset/sql.rb:229:in `_update_sql'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sequel-4.34.0/lib/sequel/dataset/sql.rb:175:in `update_sql'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sequel-4.34.0/lib/sequel/dataset/actions.rb:818:in `update'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mosql-0.4.3/lib/mosql/sql.rb:59:in `upsert!'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mosql-0.4.3/lib/mosql/streamer.rb:61:in `block (2 levels) in bulk_upsert'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mosql-0.4.3/lib/mosql/streamer.rb:39:in `unsafe_handle_exceptions'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mosql-0.4.3/lib/mosql/streamer.rb:60:in `block in bulk_upsert'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mosql-0.4.3/lib/mosql/streamer.rb:57:in `each'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mosql-0.4.3/lib/mosql/streamer.rb:57:in `rescue in bulk_upsert'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mosql-0.4.3/lib/mosql/streamer.rb:52:in `bulk_upsert'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mosql-0.4.3/lib/mosql/streamer.rb:164:in `import_collection'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mosql-0.4.3/lib/mosql/streamer.rb:122:in `block (2 levels) in initial_import'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mosql-0.4.3/lib/mosql/streamer.rb:120:in `each'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mosql-0.4.3/lib/mosql/streamer.rb:120:in `block in initial_import'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mosql-0.4.3/lib/mosql/streamer.rb:108:in `each'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mosql-0.4.3/lib/mosql/streamer.rb:108:in `initial_import'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mosql-0.4.3/lib/mosql/streamer.rb:28:in `import'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mosql-0.4.3/lib/mosql/cli.rb:167:in `run'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mosql-0.4.3/lib/mosql/cli.rb:16:in `run'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mosql-0.4.3/bin/mosql:5:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/mosql:22:in `load'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/mosql:22:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Hi jodylan - there's no attachment and no stack trace in your question; did you forget to include that?

Comment: @vincebowdren hi.. thanks for mentioning that... Added the stack trace

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to add an #sql_literal or #sql_literal_append method to `BSON::ObjectId` so that Sequel knows how to literalize it.